# Integrating Help in Qt5 C++ GUI Application

Tags: qt5, default, qthelp

I want to add the user manual for my Qt5 application as help but i am unable to find any built in tool for that.
I want to make it like Qt5 default help (without navigating user to external file or link). Help window should open right in application. I have tried QtDesktopServices and QTextBrowser. But none of them is providing the functionality as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just changed the project's user manual to html files & it worked. Also, I've set the html files as the source for my `textBrowser` as below.

```
ui->textBrowser->setSource("help.html");
```